How to get three Windows partitions and one Linux partition into Grub2?
This is a follow-up of a question at Unix.SE as it appears to be more Windows specific (the answer there could be useful here, too, I assume).
So I managed to create a quad boot system (no UEFI) with Win98 on sda1 (Fat32), WinXP on sda2 (NTFS), Win10 on sda3 (NTFS) and Debian 12 on sda4 (ext4). I installed them sequentially as mentioned. So after 98 I only had 98, after XP I got an XP bootloader with XP and 98, after Win10 I got a Win10 bootloader with Win10 and "earlier versions of Windows". When selecting "earlier versions" the PC reboots and I am presented with the XP bootloader. After Win10 I installed Debian 12 which installed Grub2 only showing the entries "Debian 12" and "Windows 10 on /dev/sda1".
What I really wanted was to have all four entries in Grub2 but it seems I have to clean up the different Windows bootloaders first. In Debian I can see all partitions just fine and can mount them, too. However, update-grub only sees the Win10 bootloader which is on sda1. Mounting the partitions doesn't change that.
On the Win98 partition I have a boot.ini with the following contents (this seems to be the WinXP bootloader):
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\ = "Microsoft Windows"

On the Win98 partition there are more boot related files: bootmgr, BOOTNXT and bootsect.dos. Where are they from? There are no boot related files on the WinXP or Win10 partitions.
The current entry in grub.cfg for "Win10 on /dev/sda1" looks like this:
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-285D-18F9' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  285D-18F9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 285D-18F9
        fi
        parttool ${root} hidden-
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}

The question is: How do I make Grub2 be able to boot all four partitions directly? Do I have to remove all Windows bootloaders first? If so, how do I do this safely?

Wasn't the main question already answered on Unix.SE? I see telcoM has even provided grub.cfg entries for directly booting each OS.

I was answered from a point of view of Grub, but the issue with the Win10 bootloader still being there remains. telcoM even said that this could be messy, so I'm asking this question here with more detail.

It seems that all three Windows installations places the boot files in the first / 98 partition. In that case, try something like:
menuentry 'Windows 98' {
        insmod fat
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        chainloader /bootsect.dos
}

menuentry 'Windows XP' {
        insmod fat
        insmod ntldr
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        ntldr /ntldr
}

menuentry 'Windows 10' {
        insmod fat
        insmod ntldr
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        ntldr /bootmgr
}


XP and 10 are on ntfs partitions, so I just replace that?

@8192K Note the first sentence (insmod fat is irrelevant to where the installations are).

Ah, I get it. The original grub.cfg entry (see edited question) had an additional "insmod part_msdos" inserted. What's that for?

Also, with your solution (will try soon), I'd still get the XP and Win10 bootloaders. Any chance to get rid of them all and boot directly into XP or Win10?

@8192K Support for the MBR/msdos type partition table. You shouldn't need the line since the root/boot directory of grub is in the Debian partition on the same drive (I suppose), so the module should be loaded automatically.

@8192K No, grub cannot boot Windows without the respective bootloader / boot manager.

So if I deleted/commented out the second line in boot.ini, which would leave only XP, would this then automatically load XP? Also, is there a way to adjust the bootmgr of Win10?

Yeah, NTLDR/BOOTMGR do a lot more than just showing the menu (much like GRUB does a lot to start Linux!), so it's going to be much easier to make NTLDR skip the boot menu by editing boot.ini, than trying to teach GRUB how to start Winload.exe (though there is a project on GitHub that does something like this) – as for Win10, the BOOTMGR equivalent of boot.ini is the binary BCD which you edit using bcdedit.exe (or graphical third-party tools like EasyBCD if I remember correctly).

This worked like a charm! Now I only have to edit the XP and Win10 boot menus.
